# Error WAT200: No default service configuration "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" could be found in the project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services

After installing Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (Version 15.1 (26403.7)) my Azure Cloud Service does no longer build and gives me the '*Error WAT200: No default service configuration "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" could be found in the project*'. Although it still works fine with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. (The right TargetProfile is also specified...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it, after disabling the '*Lightweight Solution Load*' (which in VS 2017 u can disable by right click on the *Solution* and then *Disable Lightweight Solution Load*), the error disappears and the Cloud Service builds again.

Comment: With **NO** lightweight solution load, but ReSharper Build instead of VS build, the same error happens again. So in case you have disabled lightweight solution load but trying to build via resharper, try to go with the VS build instead. (Resharper Ultimate in vers. 2017.1.2)

Comment: I have no such option in a vanilla install of VS 2017 (Enterprise).  Sooo... what the heck are you talking about?

Comment: You are right @BrainSlugs83, i am unable to understand, Manuel should upload a screenshot at least.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this last night.

It actually happens when you rename Cloud Service configurations away from `Cloud` and `Local`.

In my case, I had deleted the `Cloud` configuration and created a new, differently named one.

By ensuring that the configurations are called `Cloud` and `Local`, the Cloud Service projects will build again using "Resharper build", and (most likely) under "Lightweight solution load".

The configurations can be renamed by right-clicking one of the service roles under the Cloud Service node in Solution Explorer, choosing `Properties`, then opening up the "Service Configuration" dropdown and clicking `<Manage...>`.

[image: changing service configuration]

Now, in the resulting dialog, the configurations can be renamed:

[image: manage service configurations]

The following bug report got me on the right track:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450390

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to change the service configuration prefix in ccproj of your project, add yourprojectname.configurationname
**Dot is the life saver.**

```
<ServiceConfigurationPrefix>yourproject.ServiceConfiguration</ServiceConfigurationPrefix>
```

Add these in itemgroup:

```
<ServiceDefinition Include="yourproject.ServiceDefinition.csdef" />
<ServiceConfiguration Include="yourproject.ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" />
```

Make sure you have renamed your cscfg files from the folder it resides.

Reload

Bingo. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rishikesh mentioned, but I added a service config entry

```
<ServiceConfiguration Include="ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" />
```

to the ccproj. Then copied a configuration, e.g. Production and named it ServiceConfiguration.cscfg. Then reloaded the project. That got the ReSharper to build, but MORE importantly for me at the moment was to figure out how to the get Azure DevOps pipeline to build the solution with multiple Classic WebRole projects in it. That was failing for the SAME reason.